# CSS hover not changing correctly on chrome

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I'm developing some sort of gallery/meal picker for some web application. When I hover over those fields, those white ones, meal should appear in the middle. That works great, but when I hover over those white fields in `Chrome`, I can't see the `:hover` effect on them. It still works, but without the effect. While on `Firefox` and `IE-11` works perfectly. Here is the code link.
 http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyjKBQ

Code:

```
.dorucak {
    display: none;
}

.dorucak + label {
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 10%;
    background: white;
    /*font-size: 24px;*/
    display: inline-block;
}

.dorucak:hover + label {
    color: white;
    background: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dorucak:checked + label {
    color: white;
    background: purple; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.dorucak + label:hover {
 color: white;
 background: black;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Yea, that what I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
.dorucak:hover + label:hover {
    color: white;
    background: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

For Chrome I had to add :hover on both radio button class and label, and now it works. Sorry for posting this and fixing it a minute later.